# insert - where not exists

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to insert a record into a table if a record doesnt exist already exist with that domain name. The following SQL should achieve this but is getting an error.

The reason I want to do the update first is because I am doing multiple updates later in my code and need the record in my table first before doing all of the updates.

Why am I getting an error on this mySQL query?

```
insert into domain (name) 
values ('domain.com.au') 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
    select name 
    from domain 
    where name = 'domain.com.au'
);
```

Both queries when split work fine but when together do not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let your database handle it for you. Use a unique index on `name` and your INSERT will fail if you try to insert a duplicate.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_name ON domain (name)
```

Comment: I want to add a new record in the database as I am doing an update later on, and it needs a record in the database to do an update.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that in your question? If you want to do an INSERT when there is no record and an UPDATE if there is, use INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE.

Comment: Updated my question - I am doing the Update first - so I want to do an insert if the update does not find the domain name. I need this done before my other updates that are further down in the code.

Comment: Yes, thats what the unique index does for you. It will only let you insert the record if one with that domain name doesnt already exist.

Comment: Ok, so it will actually do an insert every time but fail because of the duplicates (if there is one) due to the key?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot combine `WHERE` with `INSERT` clause. Use  `REPLACE INTO` instead.

Answer (score 0):

What error are you getting?

My guess would be the that the select inside the 'where not exists' is not allowed.